# Youtube Script API - player showing over the top of menu items

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to embed a youtube video of mine onto my website, I am using the script API so I can have it autoplay and automuted.

The only problem im having is that the video is located just beneath my navigation menu and when a submenu drops out it is show beneath the player.

I originally had the player embedded with the iFrame script and used wmode=opaque to stop this problem which worked perfectly.

It doesnt seem to work with the script API embedding method.

Is it possible to stop this happeneing or mute using the iFrame method?

heres my YouTube script:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="ytapiplayer">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.playVideo();
    ytplayer.mute();
}
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/Du_GXK-lh4M?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&allowFullScreen=true&version=3&rel=0&wmode=opaque",
"ytapiplayer", "440", "280", "8", null, null, params, atts);
</script>
```

and the video embedding can be seen on my site here: http://create.tuscorlloyds.com/

Hoping ive posted this in the right place.

Any help would be amazing!

Many Thanks
Nick @ Tuscor Lloyds

Comment: Try Adding <param value="transparent" name="wmode"> to object tag

Comment: Hi Sarang, thanks for your help. How/where would I add that code? Could you give me a full example using the code which Ive supplied?

Comment: I think you have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding 'wmode: "transparent"' after the 'allowScriptAccess: "always"' text.

Finished code:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="ytapiplayer">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
ytplayer.playVideo();
ytplayer.mute();
}
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/Du_GXK-lh4M?enablejsapi=1&    playerapiid=ytplayer&allowFullScreen=true&version=3&rel=0",
"ytapiplayer", "440", "280", "8", null, null, params, atts);
</script>
```